# How to find prime numbers from two dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to find prime numbers in two dimensional array which is generated by random numbers. I have two functions funtion1 and function2. funtion1 is responsible for finding prime numbers in two dimensional array after that it should save prime number to one dimensional array then it should return size of one dimensional array. function1 is responsible for printing one dimensional array.

function1 takes 2 arguments two dimensional array and one dimensional array.
function2 takes 2 arguments the array and size of the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h> 
using namespace std;

int function1(int arrayA[][15],int arrayB[] );
void function2(int array[],int x);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int myA[10][15];

    int myB[150];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // ...initialize it
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {

            int row = rand() % 401 + 100;
            int column = rand() % 401 + 100;

            myA[i][j] = row, column;

            cout<< myA[i][j]<< " ";
        }
        cout<<endl; 
    }

    int x=function1(myA,myB);

    function2(myB,x);
}


int function1(int arrayA[][15],int arrayB[] ){

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                //accessing two dimensional array row
    {                                                                       
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {                          //accesing two dimensional array column

            for(int prime=2;prime<arrayA[i][j];prime++){        //for prime control

                if(arrayA[i][j]%prime!=0){

                    for(int k=0;k<150;k++){                     //keeping arrayA`s prime numbers in arrayB
                        arrayB[k]=arrayA[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    int sizeB=sizeof(arrayB)/sizeof(arrayB[0]);
return sizeB;
}   

void function2(int array[],int x){

    for(int i=0;i<x-1;i++){
        cout<<array[i];
    }
}
```

I coded solution like above but it just prints random generated two dimensional array but what I actually need is random generated two dimensional array and prime numbers of that array(output of function2)
I did not get any compile errors.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you really just asking how to determine if a number if prime? You don't currently have any logic in your code concerning prime numbers.

Comment: @davidlowryduda I know to determine prime number but I guess I am missing something in the way I am doing othwerwise it should be worked

Comment: Try to write a function that checks if a single number is prime first.

Answer (score 0):

Function 1 doesn't add prime numbers to arrayB. This array will be filled with one number. All 150 positions will have one number that isn't necessarily prime. The final check will be the last number in the 2D array % (itself minus one) which will not be 0. Hence all of arrayB will be that number.

Function 1 should returns 150 always.

The reason why function 2 has no output is that function 1 accesses a memory location or an array position that was not initialized. So there's no telling what in that memory location. Look at how you populate myA in main.

This code is very sloppy. You need to pay close attention to what you're doing. If it doesn't work in your head, it won't work when you code it.

Comment: Thank for the answers but I did not understand the part you say about "function 1 accesses a memory location or an array position that was not initialized " Can you explain it please?

Comment: What's the difference between the 2 for loops in main, vs the 2 for loops in function 1?

Comment: In the main I tired to fill myA array with the help of loops. In the function1 I tried to read the numbers inside myA with the help of first two for loops then 3rd for loop provides prime control

Comment: The array bounds in main is the problem. J needs to go to < 15 instead of < 14

Comment: I fixed it now. Now generates 10x15 array instead of 10x14. I think my problem is in function1, while reading two dimensional array on the other hand, I need to save into one dimensional